# Resize div to largest possible size when constrained by size of parent div and a aspect-ratio

Tags: javascript, html, css, aspect-ratio

**Background:**

I have the html:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="page"></div>
</div>
```

Where `#container` is a fluid element that's width and height is determined by the window size.

**Question:**

What I am trying to do is programtically set the height and width of `#page` so it **occupys the largest size it can** while being constrained by:

- It must not be larger than `#container`
- It must maintain a given aspect ratio e.g. 16:9

The part I am struggling with most its making it fill the largest size it can relative to the parent div.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure on my actual syntax, but the idea should work just fine.

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var page = document.getElementById('page');

var scale = Math.min(container.width / 16, container.height / 9)

page.width(scale * 16);
page.height(scale * 9);
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry could you explain what naturalWidth, naturalHeight and innerHeight are supposed to represent. I thought they only applied for images?

Comment: Updated it to remove the naturalHeight, naturalWidth. I didn't realize that all images would have the ratio of 16:9.

Comment: my bad I was trying to call *.naturalHeight on a div. Thank you very much this works great!

Answer (score 1):

You could also achieve the desired effect without the use of Javascript by setting the aspect ratio in the containing elements `padding-top: 56.25%;`.  The page element will need to be anchored, for example `top: 0; right: 0;`  and set you width/height to 100%.  Here is an updated JSFiddle for your review: [CLICK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/YsUHD/2/)

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="page"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 56.25%;   /*16:9 aspect ratio*/
    background:#ff0;
}
#page{
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background:red;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this JQuery code:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/YsUHD/)

```
var parentw = $("#page").parent().width();
$("#page").height(function(){
    return parentw*9/16;
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried something similar earlier, the issue was that with certain widths and heights it would cause `#page` to be taller than `#container` I really need it to be constrained by both the width and height. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/YsUHD/1/) for what I mean.